# How to save my Spyder python session as a spyder file?

Tags: python, pycharm, spyder

I am obviously new to spyder and python and I have run into a problem when I click "save as' to save my spyder script. When I try to save the file, my computer is automatically saving it into PyCharm. PyCharm is a little too complicated for me right now, so I would like to be able to save and reopen the files in spyder. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

tony

Comment: you just need to set default application to open `.py` files using spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows, right click the .py file, click open with, and find the spyder app.